# Receiving javascript heap out of memory when building Microsoft CodePush

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I only receive this error when building a CodePush release.

```
$appcenter codepush release-react -a APPNAME.com/APPNAME-ios -d Production --mandatory --output-dir ./build -t 1.x.x;

transform[stderr]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
transform[stderr]: 
transform[stderr]: Writing Node.js report to file: report.20191010.093411.22661.001.json
transform[stderr]: Node.js report completed
transform[stderr]:  1: 0x100062df2 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  2: 0x1000634eb node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  3: 0x1001aeda7 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  4: 0x1001aed44 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  5: 0x1005b5bd2 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  6: 0x1005b8103 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  7: 0x1005b4638 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  8: 0x1005b27f5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  9: 0x1005bf09c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 10: 0x1005bf11f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 11: 0x10058e314 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 12: 0x100840c54 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 13: 0x23da4894fc7d
```

How can I tell AppCenter to use `max_old_space_size=8192` ?

Comment: Your export command has only one dash as I can see. Maybe try `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` or `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"` and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

**[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/troubleshooting/react-native#my-react-native-build-fails-with-fatal-error-call_and_retry_last-allocation-failed---javascript-heap-out-of-memory) illustrates a solution to your issue.**

> On Android, add the following to the project's build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> project.ext.react = [
> nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node", "--max_old_space_size=8192"]
> ]
> ```
>
> On iOS, in Xcode, select your target and go to the Build Phases tab,
>   in the section Bundle React Native code and images, add the flag to
>   the shell script:
>
> ```
> export NODE_BINARY="'node --max_old_space_size=8192'
> ../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh"
> ```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: That's only for xcode. When I run `appcenter` CLI, I can't set the node memory there.

Comment: Can you please try running `export NODE_MEMORY=8192` before running your `code-push release-react` command.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your scripts and then run them in order.

```
"setup-fix-memory-limit": "npm install -g increase-memory-limit",
"fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=4096 increase-memory-limit",
```

Change the number in the second script to what ever you want.

```
npm run setup-fix-memory-limit
npm run fix-memory-limit
```

Also make sure to look at if it can be solved in another way, perhaps some incorrect imports are dramatically increasing the size of your bundle, use a bundle analyzer to see if what's in the build should be their, or if anything can be trimmed.

Comment: cross-env wont work with installation first

https://npm.io/package/increase-memory-limit

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22500). You could try to run this react-native bundle command :

```
node --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when running codepush on Bitrise. Solved by exporting it on `CODE_PUSH_NODE_ARGS` environment variable.

```
export CODE_PUSH_NODE_ARGS='--max_old_space_size=8192'

appcenter codepush release-react ...
```